# Dynamically create glyphicon stars in a div based on numerical value retrieved from a MSSQL database C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, bootstrap-4, glyphicons

I am retrieving a rating(can be more than 5) from the database and I want to create glyphicon stars based on the value that is received on page load. See below for code used to retrieve the value.

```
int rating_count = DBinteract.get_rating_count(ticket_id);
```

I have tried to loop through and add the glyphicons to a div, based on the value retrieved however only one star is being displayed when the page loads.

```
for (int i = 0; i < rating_count; i++)
  {
    this.rating_count.InnerHtml="<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-star'></span>";
  }
```

The div I am trying to add the stars to

```
  <td>
         <div id="rating_count" runat="server"></div>
  </td>
```

Comment: why use `i` as a variable name.  it is a horrible name.

Comment: `this.rating_count.InnerHtml += "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-star'></span>";`

Comment: @Hogan this was just an example. What would you have preferred?

Comment: @A.Ban -- you are using `i` as an index.  I would name the variable `index` or if you are a fan of really long self documenting names you could call it `currentRatingStarIndex`.  When I want to use short names I don't use `i` or `l` or `o` or `p` or `q` or `b` or `d` because they are visually similar to another single letter or hard to understand for someone with dyslexia

Comment: @Hogan okay no prob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to append the string one to each other to get more than one `span` in your generated `html`, otherwise you are assigning the same `string` multiple times to `.InnerHtml`. Even more, and f you don't already do this, take in mind that the `.innerHtml` needs to be initialized to the `empty string` first:

```
this.rating_count.InnerHtml = "";

for (int i = 0; i < rating_count; i++)
{
    this.rating_count.InnerHtml += "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-star'></span>";
    //               look here: ^^
}
```

However, if you have `Javascript` support, you could use [String.repeat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) for this task:

```
int rating_count = DBinteract.get_rating_count(ticket_id);
this.rating_count.InnerHtml = "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-star'></span>".repeat(rating_count);
```

Comment: probably want a line to init the value to an empty string before the loop.  otherwise *interesting things will happen*

Comment: @Shidersz I'm a female.

Comment: Thanks guys that worked. Totally forgot about the +=

Comment: @A.Ban Sorry for that, english is not my native language and sometimes I miss the formality, should I use `he/she` next time or there is another word inclusive for all genres?

Comment: @Shidersz "they" works, e.g. "I assume they are doing that".

Comment: @Shidersz that's okay